# Why is NUnit Framework throwing DateTime AssertionException?

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm trying to format a `DateTime`, but not change the property to a type of `string`.

My property is as follows `DateTime DateApplicationReceived = FormatDateTime();`

I have made a small function to do so which allows me to parse my `string` into a type of `DateTime`.

```
private static DateTime FormatDateTime()
{
    var format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("G");

    var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(format);
    return dateTime;
}
```

Let's say the date & time is now: 16/01/2019 15:30:00. I use NUnit to test that my function works by doing the following assert:

```
public void ConvertsTime()
{
    var sut = DateApplicationReceived;

    Assert.That(sut, Is.EqualTo("16/01/2019 15:30:00"));
}
```

My test fails. The expected result ignores the format (of "G") and displays it to a different culture `2019-01/16`.

Debug info:
[image: debug info]

Why does it do this? I'm explicity giving it a format & changing the culture variant doesn't *seem* to have any effect.

Comment: If you are having culture problems, then you need to start specifying the correct `CultureInfo` in the `ToString` and the `Parse`

Comment: @Neil as I've mentioned "changing the culture variant[/info] doesn't seem to have any effect." It's almost as if NUnit is changine the culture it itself suring the assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` object has no format.

So your code here is useless:

```
var format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("G");
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(format);
```

This is fully equivalent to

```
var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

In your unit test, you should compare either a `DateTime` with a `DateTime`, or a `string` with a `string`. Currently, you are comparing a `DateTime` with a `string`.

So you should change your code to:

```
Assert.That(sut.ToString("G"), Is.EqualTo("16/01/2019 15:30:00"));
```

or

```
Assert.That(sut, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Parse("16/01/2019 15:30:00")));
```

Comment: You got here before me. Just debugged to this solution, but thank you for your time. Also helped streamline my code as I had altered the useless code to: `var dt = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("G");` Yours is much better.

Comment: I like the former, will not give problems if locales change.